# How to save registration details ( text and image) to firebase using ionic 4 angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and angular but have been doing some coding projects to work up my skills. On of the things i am trying to accomplish is a registration page where user details and an image are saved to Firebase.

This is the code for the registration.ts page

```
            import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
            import { Router } from '@angular/router';
            import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
            import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
            import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
            import { WebView } from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx';

            //Image picker
            import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker/ngx';

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-register',
              templateUrl: './register.page.html',
              styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss']
            })

            export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {
              public email: string;
              public password: string;
              spinner: boolean = false;
              disabled: boolean = false;
              image: any;
              item: any;
              loading: any;

              constructor(
                private route: Router,
                private menuCtrl: MenuController,
                private auth: AuthService,
                private imagePicker: ImagePicker,
                public toastController: ToastController,
                private webview: WebView
              ) {
                this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
              }

              ngOnInit() {
                this.auth.user.subscribe(res => {
                  if (res && res.uid) {
                    console.log(res)
                    this.auth.getUser(res.uid).then(user => {
                      this.spinner = false;
                      this.disabled = false;
                      if (user['approved'] === false) {
                        this.route.navigate(['approved']);
                      } else {
                        this.route.navigate(['home']);
                      }
                    });
                  }
                });
              }

              register() {
                this.spinner = true;
                this.disabled = true;
                // console.log('Email', this.email, 'Password', this.password);
                this.auth
                  .signupUser(this.email, this.password)
                  .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    //added image to writeNewUser 
                    this.auth.writeNewUser(this.email, res.user.uid, this.image)
                      .then(response => {
                        this.auth.getUser(res.user.uid).then(user => {
                          this.spinner = false;
                          this.disabled = false;
                          this.route.navigate(['approved']);
                        });
                      })
                  })
                  .catch(async err => {
                    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
                      header: 'Authentication Error',
                      message: err.message,
                      position: 'bottom',
                      buttons: [{
                        text: 'Okey',
                        role: 'cancel',
                        handler: () => {
                          console.log('Cancel clicked');
                        }
                      }
                      ]
                    });
                    toast.present();
                    this.spinner = false;
                    this.disabled = false;
                    console.log(err.message);
                  });
                // this.route.navigate(['verify-otp']);
              }

              //open image picker method
              openImagePicker(){
                this.imagePicker.hasReadPermission()
                .then((result) => {
                  if(result == false){
                    // no callbacks required as this opens a popup which returns async
                    this.imagePicker.requestReadPermission();
                  }
                  else if(result == true){
                    this.imagePicker.getPictures({
                      maximumImagesCount: 1
                    }).then(
                      (results) => {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            this.getImage(results[i]);
                        }
                      }, (err) => console.log(err)
                    );
                  }
                }, (err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                });
              }

              getImage(image){
                this.loading.present();
                image = this.webview.convertFileSrc(image);

                let randomId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
                console.log(randomId);

                /***
                //uploads img to firebase storage
                this.firebaseService.uploadImage(image, randomId)
                .then(photoURL => {
                  this.image = photoURL;
                  this.loading.dismiss();
                  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                    message: 'Image was updated successfully',
                    duration: 3000
                  });
                  toast.present();
                })

                ****/
              }

              login() {
                this.route.navigate(['login']);
              }
            }
```

This is the auth.ts page code:

```
            import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
            import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
            import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
            import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

            import { AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
            @Injectable({
              providedIn: 'root'
            })
            export class AuthService {
              user: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
              driversCollectionReference: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

              constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
                this.checkUser();
              }

              signupUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
                return this.afAuth.auth
                  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
              }

               writeNewUser(email: string, uid: string, image: any): Promise<any> {
                console.log(uid, email)
                return this.db
                  .collection('drivers')
                  .doc(uid)
                  .set({
                    email: email,
                    available: false,
                    approved: false
                  });
              }

              loginUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
                return this.afAuth.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
              }
```

}

How can both registration details and image be saved in to a Firebase collection?

Comment: arent u doing that already `this.auth.writeNewUser(this.email, res.user.uid, this.image)`?

Comment: hi @PeterHaddad, i am not sure where I am going wrong because its not running

Comment: is `register()` a button? Also what is this `console.log('Email', this.email, 'Password', this.password);` giving you and this `console.log(res);`?

Comment: register() is the function called when the 'sign up' button is clicked. console.log('Email', this.email, 'Password', this.password) ...... this was done initially when I was using only firebase authentication to display email and password when debugginh

Comment: ok but what does it give you? And what does this `console.log(res);` give you?

Comment: res is  an array that returns user values for example user id, etc from the , in this case, 'drivers' collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204473/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-user3682205).

Comment: what is the error with the image picker?

Answer (score 0):

Since the image is added in the firebase storage, to also add it in the collection do the following:

```
.collection('drivers')
.doc(uid)
.set({
      email: email,
      available: false,
      approved: false,
      image : image
});
```

Here the image will contain the `imageURL`, which you can retrieve later